# Can any one explain this code how i use this in my application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a problem similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334846/connecting-lines-while-dragging-in-flex-actionscript) question but i'm not able to get understand this answer code, Can any one explain this code.

```
private function attachListeners():void
{
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, selfMouseDownHandler, false,0,true);
    this.addEventListener(MoveEvent.MOVE, selfMoveHandler, false,0,true);
}

private function selfMoveHandler(event:MoveEvent):void
{
    redrawConnectedLinks();
}

private function selfMouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageMouseUpHandler, false,0,true);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stageMouseMoveHandler, false,0,true);
}

private function stageMouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageMouseUpHandler, false);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stageMouseMoveHandler, false);
}

private function stageMouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dispatchEvent(new MoveEvent(MoveEvent.MOVE));
}
```

Please suggest me how to use this in  flex application.

Comment: On Stackoverflow it is better to ask specific questions.  Explain the problem you're having and what you tried to do to solve it and why it didn't work.  Telling us you have the "Same" problem as some other question isn't usually well recieved; which is why you're getting close votes.  No one wants to read another question to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code is tracking mouse movement by Flash's MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE and MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN.
Along with those events, the code is using a custom Event: MoveEvent.MOVE.

Any time, a MoveEvent.MOVE is being dispatched, the app would redraw the connectors. So, a listener to MoveEvent.MOVE is being added once and for all at the beginning.

Also, to track a drag, this code waits for MOUSE_DOWN and then keep on dispatching MoveEvent.MOVE for each MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE until a MOUSE_UP event occurs.

Now, let me associate the above explanation to the lines of code:

```
private function attachListeners():void
{
    /*Wait for mouse down event to initiate mouse move and mouse up tracking*/
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, selfMouseDownHandler, false,0,true);

    /*Always track MoveEvent.MOVE and start redrawing connectors whenever it's dispatched*/
    this.addEventListener(MoveEvent.MOVE, selfMoveHandler, false,0,true);
}

private function selfMoveHandler(event:MoveEvent):void
{
    /*Redraw connectors when the custom event MoveEvent.MOVE is received*/
    redrawConnectedLinks();
}

private function selfMouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    /*Wait for mouse up event on receiving a mouse down*/
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageMouseUpHandler, false,0,true);
    /*Track mouse movement once mouse is down*/
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stageMouseMoveHandler, false,0,true);
}

private function stageMouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    /*Once mouse up happens stop tracking mouse up... */
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageMouseUpHandler, false);
    /*Don't track mouse movement once mouse button gets released*/
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stageMouseMoveHandler, false);
}

private function stageMouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    /*dispatch MoveEvent.MOVE when mouse is moved.
      If you read the above setup again, this should get dispatched on mouse moves
      happening after a mouse down and before a mouse up
     */
    dispatchEvent(new MoveEvent(MoveEvent.MOVE));
}
```

HTH.

***Explanation of custom events as asked in the comment by OP***

Custom events are useful to add custom message passing semantics. e.g. in this case, mouse drag is a detected by a series of mouse events, and once those events happen a custom event is dispatched to notify the connectors should be redrawn. Similarly, you might have a refresh button and clicking on it might dispatch the same event to force redraw.

Comment: thanks mr@catholicon,but what is purpose of custom event? when they useful?

Comment: Updated answer to explain that